# What is the account of Vishnu and Brahma not being able to eat and creating a demi-god to "eat"?

Tags: gods, death

What is the account of Vishnu and Brahma not being able to eat and creating a demi-god who would "eat" for them? I'm not sure if I got major Gods right.

Comment: Agni through his mouth consumes the offerings made in Yajnas to Gods as well as trimurtis and delivers them to respected deities. In hinduism scriptures like puranas  Agni is also created god by Trimurties and besides other tasks does the above one for them.